# Regular Expression to accept only positive numbers and decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression in javascript that will accept only positive numbers and decimals.  This is what I have but something is wrong -- it doesn't seem to take single positive digits.

```
/^[-]?[0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]+$/;
```

For example, `9` will not work. How can I restructure this so if there is at least one positive digit, it will work?

Comment: Since you have + after each [0-9] character class, numbers without decimals will have to be at least two digits long.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
/^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\.][0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$/
```

matches

```
0
+0
1.
1.5
.5
```

but not

```
.
1..5
1.2.3
-1
```

EDIT:

To handle scientific notation (`1e6`), you might want to do

```
/^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\.][0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$/
```

If you want strictly positive numbers, no zero, you can do

```
/^[+]?([1-9][0-9]*(?:[\.][0-9]*)?|0*\.0*[1-9][0-9]*)(?:[eE][+-][0-9]+)?$/
```

Comment: @MikeChristensen, it doesn't handle scientific notation, but you can slap an optional `[eE][+-]?[0-9]+` before the `$` to handle that.

Comment: How to add length constraint in it , say only allow to number after point ex- 12.22 is valid but 12.123 not

Comment: @Saurabh, you'd have to modify the [0-9]* and [0-9]+ to use a range count instead: `/^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\.][0-9]{0,2})?|\.[0-9]{1,2})$/`

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thanks , it works to validate to digit after point but not before point , I tried to modify like /^[+]?([0-9]{0,2}+(?:[\.][0-9]{0,2})?|\.[0-9]{1,2})$/ to limit value before point to 2 digit , example max value can be 99.99 and in positive

Answer (score 3):

There are few different ways to do this depending on your need:

`/^[0-9.]+$/` matches `1` and `1.1` but not `-1`

`/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/` matches `1.1` but not `1` or `-1`

Generally, I recommend using a simple regExp reference guide like http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for building expressions, and then test them using javascript right your browser console:

`"123.45".match(/^[0-9.]+$/)`

Comment: That will also include `...` and so on.

Comment: True that -- seemed like the question was broader before it was edited.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this -

```
^\d{0,10}(\.\d{0,2})?$
```

Also one cool site to test as well as to get description of your own regular expressions 
https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

How about like:

```
^[.]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$
```

Comment: Won't that also match things like `.0.0`?

Answer (score 1):

I have found something interesting which work for me!!!
hope so for you also...!!!

[0-9]*.[0-9]*

Regex for accepting only a positive number with a decimal point

Matches: 
   1, 2564, 2.5545, 254.555

Not Matches:
   -333, 332.332.332, 66-665.455, 55554-4552

Answer (score 0):

I have done one in case people are interested:
^([0-9]*)(.[[0-9]+]?)?$

but it doesn't have '+' sign
while also it doesn't accept '-' sign

It accepts:

```
0
0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5
3.0
1
2
3
4
0.0
0.1
0.9
0.4
1.3
1.11
1.51
2.01
01.5
0.51
1.1
.1
```

Reject:

```
-1.0
-0.5
-0.0
-0.1
-0.7
11123.
1.001.
.1.1
```