# Regex with or statement

Tags: regex

I need to build a Regex that matches two different pattern. So I need to validate strings that are match the regex: `/^[\d]*.{0,1}[\d]{0,2}$` which basically means any positive float number or just the symbol "-"

I thought that the regex: `/^[\d]*.{0,1}[\d]{0,2}$|^[-]$/` would do the job, but it accepts any number or any single symbol. Does anyone have a regex that would work for this?

Comment: Does this help? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708333/regular-expression-to-accept-only-positive-numbers-and-decimals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that `.` matches *any character*, not just a period.  So this:

```
^[\d]*.{0,1}[\d]{0,2}$
```

Matches any single character line.  `[\d]*` happily matches 0 characters, and so does `[\d]{0,2}`, which leaves you with `.{0.1}`, or 0-1 of any character.  You can escape the period with a backslash.

```
^[\d]*\.{0,1}[\d]{0,2}$|^-$
```

Although, I would clean up a bit more.  `[\d]` could just be `\d`, and `\.{0,1}` can be written `\.?`

```
^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$|^-$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot the fact that the period has to be escaped. I just had to change a little bit your regex to make it work: ^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$|^-$ This allows to match all patterns ###.## or ### or just -

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
/^([\d]*.{0,1}[\d]{0,2}|\-)$/
```

Just a warning though. The regex you provided allows for negative integers, so something like `-14` will validate. I don't know if that is intended, but I left it that way.