# Validation error in angular input[type=number]?

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-template

I have a strange problem when trying to validate `input[type=number]` in Angular 7 and hope that somebody can help.

```
    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="entranceFee" min="0" [(ngModel)]="entranceFee" #entranceFee="ngModel" pattern="\\d+" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': entranceFee.touched && entranceFee.invalid }" >
    <div *ngIf="entranceFee.invalid && entranceFee.touched" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="entranceFee.errors.pattern">Only numbers are permitted</div>
        <div *ngIf="entranceFee.errors.min">Value cannot be smaller than '0'</div>
    </div>
```

The input shall only accept `numbers >= 0`. But whenever I enter a number value (0-9) the form becomes invalid. Why? When I output the ngModel in the console in `ngAfterViewChecked()` a number value was written to the model. So how can I validate this form? Is there a bug in the validator or in my head?

The same happens when implementing this code with reactive forms and/or with `input[type=text]`

Comment: It's a number input, so using pattern is useless. The input only accepts numbers. And `min` is not a validation directive. It's only a standard html attribute that the browser uses to prevent you from spinning belos the minimum.

Comment: not really, because it is possible to enter the letter "e". 1e1 makes sense but you can also enter e.g. "eeee"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<input 
  class="form-control" 
  type="number" 
  name="entranceFee"
  #entranceFee="ngModel"  
  [(ngModel)]="entranceFee.value"
  pattern="^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\.][0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$"
  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': entranceFee.touched && entranceFee.invalid }" >

<div *ngIf="entranceFee.invalid && entranceFee.touched" class="invalid-feedback">
  <div *ngIf="entranceFee.errors.pattern">Only numbers are permitted</div>
  <div *ngIf="entranceFee.errors.min">Value cannot be smaller than '0'</div>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcqnpf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

---

RegEx Courtesy - [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7708352/2622292)